# Azure B2C Custom Policy - Catching the verify email address before an email verification is sent

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We want to restrict what email addresses the password reset verification is sent to.
The email should only be sent to know email addresses.
We also want to limit the number of such requests (per period - say 3 attempts over 30 mins)

With a custom policy I am able to catch the email address after the verification code has been sent and before the password reset is attempted.

I added a new Orchestration step the "PasswordReset" user UserJourney (see below). This gave made a claims call, but it was made before the validation email address was entered and was only made once.

```
    <UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Pre_PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Pre_LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```